json schema which either contains properties B and C or D
I defined the following schema:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/test",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "B": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "C": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "D": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


The idea is that the schema contains A, and either (B AND C) OR D. None of the elements are required (thus A is actually not part of the question/problem)
The following instance fails to validate:
{
  "A": "Hello",
  "D": "World"
}


It contains A (irrelevant, as not required anyway) and D, which should be covered by anyOf.

I believe you want anyOf instead of oneOf, because oneOf checks for exactly one of the subschemas, but in your test instance you don't have one of the subschemas. The docs are here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining#oneOf  and you can test your schema here: https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/ which is where I find anyOf works in your case.

I tried oneOf instead of anyOf and indeed it validates. However, this does not express my intent: An Object which contains A and either (B AND C) OR D.   As none of the elements are required, if the object contains B OR C , there must be no D and vice versa. anyOf, even according to the spec you linked, seemed the correct approach, but doesn't work. I slightly edited the question to make that more clear. BTW I am already using an offline helper of the hyperjump lib to do the validation.

I see, thank you for clarifying the logic. I think your schema will need to be changed. I'll try to update my answer later today.

@JohnDoe my apologies, I wasn't able to find a solution based on your clarification.

If you find a solution please post it!

I suggest the following approach. Define all your properties together and then add a constraint to express your requirement.
{
  "properties": {
    "A": {},
    "B": {},
    "C": {},
    "D": {}
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["B", "C"] },
    { "required": ["D"] }
  ]
}

Either "B" and "C" must be present or "D" must present, but not both. "A" may or may not be present with either option.
UPDATE
If neither ("B" and "C") nor "D" should also be valid, you'll need to add an option to the oneOf that expresses that intent. In this example, the last schema disallows "B", "C", and "D". So, the schema either has ("A" and "B") XOR "D" XOR none of those properties.
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["B", "C"] },
    { "required": ["D"] },
    {
      "properties": {
        "B": false,
        "C": false,
        "D": false
      }
    }
  ]


Doesn't work, an instance like{
"A": "world"
} fails to validate as now (B, C) OR (D) are required.

Ahh. It wasn't clear from your question that neither (B, C) or (D) was valid. I'll revise the answer.
